# using gmail as your email hosting provider?

Tags: smtp, gmail

i've got a external domain and i want gmail to handle all the incoming emails.

i know that its free for me to let gmail handle all the outgoing mails, since you can add your external domain in their settings.

but how about incoming mails? is it free or do i have to use their google apps for business?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Google Apps Standard Edition -- they don't publicize it much but it's there. It's free but you're limited to 50 users and there are ads on the webmail pages.